# cannot load certificate "/etc/ssl/ServerCertificate.crt": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory

Tags: docker, nginx, https, dockerfile, nginx-reverse-proxy

this is my docker file

```
# stage1 - build react app first 

FROM node:12.16.1-alpine3.9 as build

WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY ./package.json /app/

COPY ./package-lock.json /app/

RUN npm i --silent

COPY . /app

RUN npm run build



# stage 2 - build the final image and copy the react build files

FROM nginx:1.17.8-alpine

COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
COPY ServerCertificate.crt /etc/ssl/
COPY 2022pk.key /etc/ssl/



EXPOSE 443

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

and this in the nginx.conf file

```
server {



  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/ServerCertificate.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/2022pk.key;
  server_name *.com;



  location / {

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;

    index  index.html index.htm;



    # to redirect all the requests to index.html, 

    # useful when you are using react-router



    try_files $uri /index.html; 

  }



  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;



  location = /50x.html {

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;

  }



}
```

I'm getting Error

cannot load certificate "/root/etc/ssl/ServerCertificate.crt": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/root/etc/ssl/ServerCertificate.crt','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)

Answer (score -2):

Added port 80 in Expose and it worked!!

Comment: What do you mean Expose? Thanks.

Comment: Expose is the port you publish to while using docker run. For example: docker run --publish [image port]:[expose port]